# Is it possible to have custom error response with jwt authentication?

Tags: java, spring, jwt, response, handler

I started building my project based on a custom error response in order to send the json body with only fields that i need. For this reason i have a

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

that catches all exceptions and returns ResponseEntity having ther custom error body.

I have a postgres database where i save users. Currently i have /signin, /signup and /profile endpoints. I wanted to use jwt authentication. I used [this github repo](https://github.com/murraco/spring-boot-jwt/tree/master/src/main/java/murraco/security) and i can get the token when i send user's credentials on the /signin endpoint.

Here's the problem. Read this part of JwtTokenFilter.java

```
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
    try {
      if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
        Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
      }
    } catch (CustomException ex) {
      //this is very important, since it guarantees the user is not authenticated at all
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      httpServletResponse.sendError(ex.getHttpStatus().value(), ex.getMessage());
      return;
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
  }
```

Suppose i want to signup a new user. Then my request's header won't have a token (token is null) and the program will execute `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);`. That work's fine, the user gets signed up and i get the `201` that my controller returns upon successful registration.
However, suppose i make a GET request at /profile endpoint again having no token. This too will execute filterChain.doFilter. However this time spring will respond with a **NON-custom** `403` error response.
I can't find a way to catch the exception on my RestControllerHandler because spring handles it for me.

Also, when i throw an exception inside `doFilterInternal`, the exception again won't be handled by my GlobalHandler, spring handles it.

Answer (score 1):

Will have to add custom AuthenticationFailureHandler

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler 
  implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(
  HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response,
  AuthenticationException exception) 
  throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(
      "timestamp", 
      Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    data.put(
      "exception", 
      exception.getMessage());

    response.getOutputStream()
      .println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
 }
}
```

and then configure this here

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
  throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder.encode("user1Pass")).roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) 
  throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }
}
```